# ConcurrentHashMap as cache

Tags: java, caching, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

if a ConcurrentHashMap is used as map I ask myself what is the correct way to achieve thread safety?

In a book I found someting like this:

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<KEY, VALUE> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public V put(KEY key, VALUE value) {
    VALUE ret = cache.get(key);
    if (ret == null) {
        ret = cache.putIfAbsent(key, value);
        if (ret == null) {
            ret = value;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Now I ask myself isn't it necessary to make the the get and possible put atomic like this:

```
public V put(KEY key, VALUE value) {
    synchronized(cache) {
        VALUE ret = cache.get(key);
        if (ret == null) {
            ret = cache.putIfAbsent(key, value);
            if (ret == null) {
                ret = value;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Because when cache.get() returns null, another thread could invalidate the cache.get() result for the 1st thread?

Cheers
Oliver

Comment: so what exactly is your question about it?

Comment: My question was if it is necessary to put the calls cache.get(...) and cache.putIfAbsent(...) inside a synchronized block and use the cache monitor.

Comment: no, it's not necessary.  `putIfAbsent` handles the atomicity for you (as it states in the javadoc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary.

It is true that following code would not  be thread-safe as a result of `cache.get()` can be invalidate by another thread.

```
VALUE ret = cache.get(key);
if (ret == null) {...}
```

However, the code is there just for an optimization (atomic operations are more expensive). Atomicity is ensured by `map.putIfAbsent()` which is atomic and therefore thread-safe. Nevertheless, if `cache.get()` returns something else then `null`, expensive atomic operation does not perform.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply with lazy initialization with in synchronize block.

```
    private static volatile ConcurrentHashMap<KEY, VALUE> cache = null;

    public static ConcurrentHashMap<KEY, VALUE> getCacheInstance() {
        if (cache == null) {
            synchronized(cache) {
                if (cache == null) {
                    cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
                }
            }
        }
        return cache ;
    }

    public static put(ConcurrentHashMap<KEY, VALUE> cache) {
        VALUE ret = cache.get(KEY);
        if (ret == null) {...
        }     
    }
```

In Java 8 implement local thread-safe cache is very easy.

```
    private static final ConcurrentMap<KEY, VALUE> cache = 
                                          new ConcurrentHashMap();

    public Object get(String KEY) {
       return cache.computeIfAbsent(KEY, k - > createObject(k));
    }
```

You can implement it in Java 7 with double checking thread safety.

```
    public Object get(String KEY) {
        if (!cache.containsKey(KEY)) {
            synchronized (cache) {
               if (!cache.containsKey(KEY)) {
                   cache.put(KEY, createObject(KEY));
               }
            }
        }
        return cache.get(KEY);
    }
```

https://developer-should-know.com/post/116472734172/local-thread-safe-cache-with-java